# combining multiple results into one row in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a simple survey that I need to report on using SSRS.

It has 2 questions.  One question can have multiple selections like below:

*What is your name?*

*Pick your favorite colors* (`Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Brown, Purple`)?

Here are sample query results:

```
Tim       Red
Tim       Blue
Tim       Green
Mary      Yellow
George    Brown
George    Red
Jill      Purple
```

I'd like to combine them like this so that they all appear on one row in the report showing the selected answers in bold(or a different color) and the unselected answers just as plain text.

`Tim:`      **Red**, **Blue**, **Green**, Yellow, Brown, Purple

`Mary:`     Red, Blue, Green, **Yellow**, Brown, Purple

`George:`   **Red**, Blue, Green, Yellow, **Brown**, Purple

`Jill:`   Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Brown, **Purple**

I tried using this expression in my report:

```
Join(Fields!favoriteColors.Value, ", ")
```

However I would just see #Error in my report.

Is something like this possible in SSRS 2008R2?

Comment: Please explain what tools or technologies you're using.

Comment: Are your users using parameters to fill the survey? Or are you reporting the results from a existing database?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I'm using a dataset from a database. There are no report parameters. Thanks

Comment: @JeffersonLima sorry, SSRS connected to a SQL Server 2012 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the **JOIN** doesn't work on a Grouping basis like you would think.

You can cheat and do it this way in your situation:

```
=JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Color.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

This will look up the values in the dataset based on the **Name** and combine the **Colors** with a comma seperator.

**But** this will only get the **selected** colors - not all colors. I think you would need another query for unpicked colors and combine them. You can use HTML markup for the **bold**ening.

```
="<b>" & JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Color.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
& "</b>" & JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Color.Value, "DataSet2"), ", ")
```

Query for unpicked colors:

```
SELECT Name, Color FROM 
(select DISTINCT Color from #COLORS ) C
CROSS JOIN 
(select DISTINCT Name from #COLORS ) N 
EXCEPT SELECT Name, Color FROM  #COLORS
```

Comment: Would this require a separate dataset?  Or could I just use the existing one?  Thanks!

Comment: For the unpicked colors you would need a separate dataset with the query to identify each users unpicked colors OR you could write a VB function in SSRS to do it - though the VB would be a bit more work.

Comment: I added a sample query based on your dataset for the unpicked.